# How to get locale within WP REST Request?

Tags: plugin-development, rest-api, multi-language, localization

When sending requests to the WP REST API / custom WP REST endpoints, which is the way to go to retrieve the current locale; a universal way which always works? I'm confused by the many functions available, like [determine_locale](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/determine_locale/), [get_locale](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_locale/), or even plugin functions like [pll_current_language](https://polylang.pro/doc/function-reference/#pll_current_language) with Polylang.

The reason why I'm asking this is because the retrieved locales are inconsistent; sometimes `get_locale()` returns the root language (e.g. `de`)  for a page which is actually in french (language attribute in html also set to `fr-FR`), etc.

So it seems like the according values are only available at a certain moment / specific hooks, and not simply always within a WP REST callback. Hence, which is the way to go to retrieve the current locale of the client within a WP REST Request callback?

Comment: posts and pages don't have locales, if they do on your site it's because a plugin is providing them and you would need to ask the plugin for it. Remember WordPress has no mechanism for translatable dynamic content, only translated static strings in code, so asking how to get the locale of a post in WordPress makes no sense without a plugin, and your solution is heavily dependent on which plugin you chose to use. **It's very likely that what you ask for is impossible to answer here because it requires you to use Polylang specific functions and 3rd party plugins are offtopic here**

Comment: All I wondered is if WP does not have a core function to retrieve the locale of the client within the callback hooked to a custom WP REST API request, defined in your main plugin file, via `register_rest_route`. So the answer to that seems to be *no* according to your comment, cheers! And of course also many thanks to @Jacob!

Comment: the answer is yes you can, but that answer doesn't fit into the system Polylang sets up, which is why you get inconsistencies. E.g. requests for a french article that return english for the user locale, because French is not the current users locale in native WP and your expectations have muddled up content locale and user locale together. There will be a unique Polylang specific answer that you need for your situation

Comment: Always a pleasure to learn from you mate, cheers!

Comment: And just in case, let's say I could retrieve the locale within the callback, and it's for example `fr-FR`. How would you in this case set the locale of WP, such that for example `echo __('Hello there','my-custom-plugin')` is echoed out in its french version, if available? I'd say that would need to be done on the end of WP and not polylang, WPML or whatever, as it's WP native? Or am I wrong again, and it's plugin-specific too?

Comment: WPML/Polylang/etc/etc all have their own solutions to this and track the current locale in different ways, be that via cookies or the location on the site you're at etc etc. There are many ways to do multilingual that have their own tradeoffs, you need to work within the system you chose, there is no generic one size fits all solution that works for all plugins everywhere. Until the translation phase of the gutenberg project starts that won't change ( and that's potentially years away )

Comment: Yeah I'm thinking of migrating my [gettext translations](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/) into custom plugin translations, as done with [pll_register_string](https://polylang.pro/doc/function-reference/#pll_register_string), [pll__](https://polylang.pro/doc/function-reference/#pll__) and [pll_e](https://polylang.pro/doc/function-reference/#pll_e). I'm just worried about performance regarding the retrieval of the localizations, but guess that's another story..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's only 2 real places a locale is defined in a vanilla WordPress install:

1. For the site.
2. For the user account.

In the admin the user account's locale will be used, while on the front end the site's locale will be used. For REST API requests the user locale can be used by passing `_locale=user` as a parameter.

The `determine_locale()` function is what performs the logic to determine whether the user or site's locale should be used, with additional logic that handles setting the locale during install.

The `get_locale()` function is used by `determine_locale` to get the *site's* locale. It returns the site's language as set in *Settings > General*. The site language can also be defined as a constant in `wp-config.php` or filtered by plugins. This is the function you'd normally use to get a site's locale.

Individual pages and posts do not have a locale. If you are using a plugin to create versions of pages in multiple languages then you will need to refer to that plugin's documentation for the correct way to get the correct language.

If you're asking how to get the user's *location*, then that's something else entirely, and not something WordPress can do. To accomplish that you will either need to use JavaScript in the browser to ask the user to share their location, or use a database of IP addresses to estimate the user's location. WordPress does not provide a function for either of these things.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly; your suggestion is to pass `_locale=user` to all of my REST API requests fired from the client-side, without the client being logged in into the admin, and then calling `get_locale()` within the callback you hook on your custom WP REST endpoint, to retrieve the locale properly? Another problem we have is that even our built-in translations created with WPs' built-in `__()` functions are returned in the sites' root language, instead of the language of the page of the frontend the client uses to makes the request. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: I'm asking the thing about `_locale=user` because I cannot find any documentation about it.

Comment: "Another problem we have is that even our built-in translations created with WPs' built-in __() functions are returned in the sites' root language, instead of the page of the frontend the client uses to makes the request." As I covered in my answer: pages do not have languages. So I would not expect the functions to use any other language except the site's language. If you expect a different language because you are using a plugin to set the language for a page, then you will need to take that question to the plugin developer.

Comment: But based on which principle do the localization functions `__()` for themes and plugins then work on the frontend?? In this context, do you have any idea if WP will indeed integrate multilinguality within its [core](https://wordpress.org/about/roadmap/) ? Would be cool to not need to rely on plugins for multiple languages anymore..

Comment: They will display the text in the site's chosen language if translations are available in that language.

Comment: And by the site's chosen language; you mean..... ? The value of the `lang` attribute of the HTML page? or what determines the site's chosen language?

Comment: The language set in _Settings > General_.

Comment: Yeah I got that, but there you can only set a single language, and it makes no sense to me to use `__()` functions if you only use one language?? Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: Why doesn't it make sense? If I'm a Spanish user and I set my site language to Spanish, then how else are plugins supposed to be able to use Spanish if their code is written in English? The `__()` functions support translating text in theme and plugin code into multiple languages.

Comment: Multilingual plugins can hook into these functions to allow user translations or to support other ways of changing the language, but again, you'd need to ask their developers about functionality specific to their plugin.

Comment: When you talk about user, you talk about users of the admin area, right? Then of course it makes sense, as one single admin user needs to have one single language served at the same time. But I'm talking about the frontend, accessed by customers of your webshop etc., for which customer X may needs to access the page in spanish, others in english, etc. For this case thus, according to your comments, there's absolutely no connection from these multiple language feature with the language you set for a WP admin user, and a plugin is needed to control all of that?

Comment: And to thus answer my question; vanilla WP has actually *no way* to retrieve the locale of the client within the callback of a WP REST API request, the request coming from the frontend, from a client who's not logged into the admin?

Comment: Correct, WordPress does not have any way to get the user's location in a REST API callback. It has no way to get the user's location in any circumstances.

Comment: I meant language, not geographical location, just to avoid misunderstandings here. Cheers! Hopefully the core implementation of multilinguality will come soon, that will open many doors I guess.. So I guess the only workaround for this is to pass a `lang` parameter or whatever explicitly to every single API call, for now..

Comment: I would not count on WordPress adding multilingual support any time soon.

Comment: To back-pedal a bit: There is an `Accept-Language` header that browser may send that may indicate the user's preferred language. Probably the browser language. However this isn't necessarily the same format that WordPress uses, and WordPress's functions don't use it. I can't say whether multilanguage plugins use it either. You may be able to retrieve the value with PHP, but the code for that wouldn't be WordPress specific.

Comment: Yep sure. And again just to confirm; the `_locale=user` option is only possible for logged in WP Admin Users sending requests, right? Just to be clear on that one too; and thx for your patience!

Comment: All it does is set the language to whatever is set on the user's profile, which means they need to be logged into WordPress.

Comment: Ok got it. Yeah the hint with the header is cool, but I guess I'll stick to a universal, custom URL parameter. Sth like [this](https://github.com/polylang/polylang/issues/160). Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Given that I've struggled significantly with this, I'd like to share my solution. Note that the solution aims to retrieve the requesting client's locale within a WP REST Request, incoming from the frontend part of your application, hence from a user who's not logged in into the WP admin, in a reliable way, such that:

- `__()` localization functions get the translations in the requesting client's locale, instead of the default language of your website.
- WP core functions like `get_locale()` return the retrieved client's locale, instead of the default locale of your website.

So here's my approach:

1. Create a Wrapper function in javascript, which you then use to fire all  requests to the WP REST API from your frontend application. Within that wrapper function, pass a custom HTTP header that is specific to your plugin, sth like `X-MYPLUGIN-LANG`. I could have used `Accept-Language`, but as you may use a plugin for multilingual functionality already, that header may be affected by that plugin at some stage. So just to avoid any eventual code conflicts, I've decided to use a custom HTTP header.
2. The value of that header is equal to `document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].lang`; determined once only on page load.
3. Within the main plugin file of the plugin where your targeted endpoints are registered via `register_rest_route`, you most likely have some code somewhere which loads your plugin's textdomain. Something like:

```
add_action(
                'init',
                function () {
                    
                    load_plugin_textdomain(
                        'my-plugin',
                        false,
                        dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__)) . '/languages'
                    );

                }
            );
```

From what I've learned, this hook is what loads your localizations from your `.mo` files of the concerned plugin in the language represented by the current value of `get_locale()`. I've tested that by just putting an `echo get_locale()` before the `load_plugin_textdomain()` call above, and indeed: The translations of all of the `__()` all happen in the language represented by the output of `get_locale()`. So what must be done is (my thoughts, at least): change the locale for the lifetime of the incoming request, if it's a custom REST API request, into the one of the requesting client. And as well, for the entire lifetime of the incoming request, do this only once; to avoid repeated calls. This is assured by the fact that you'll enter your code within the action hooking above, as the `init` hook is executed exactly once with every request.

My conclusion was thus to add code that does the following above `load_plugin_textdomain()` (I won't paste the code as your validation may differs, etc.):

1. Check if the incoming request has a `X-MYPLUGIN-LANG` HTTP header set.
2. If so, verify that its value matches a valid locale of your REST API, before doing anything else (input validation).
3. If so, remember that the value of your HTTP header is retrieved from the `html` tags' `lang` attribute, hence sth like `en-US`. WP locales however seem to work with underscores; hence transform the locale obtained from the client accordingly; hence sth like `en-US` --> `en_US`. Although I do not know if that step is strictly necessary.
4. Simply call `switch_to_locale(<your_transformed_locale>)`.

Doing the above-mentioned within your callback hooked to your `init` hook, right above `load_plugin_textdomain()`, returned all of my `__()` translations in the client's language, and `get_locale()` can also be used for other stuff, now retrieving the correct client locale, too!

**UPDATE**

As weird as things can get, when using `rest_pre_dispatch` and short-circuiting your response to your custom request, the `init` hook gets executed, hence the locale gets successfully changed to your client's locale, but the translations retrieved via `__()` calls are still in the root website language. Even if I `echo get_locale()` right above `echo __('test translation','my-plugin')`, and I get a locale different from the default locale, `test translation` gets output instead of its translation in the output locale. The reason so far seems to be that the call to `load_plugin_textdomain()` failed; as it returns `false`. I'm puzzled.

**UPDATE 2**

The call of `load_plugin_textdomain()` (and if it actually succeeds) seems to be completely irrelevant. It seems to be more crucial to which locale you switch via `switch_to_locale` before outputting the response holding localizations with `__()`. I've noticed this because, within WP REST requests which are entirely executed (hence not short-circuited via `rest_pre_dispatch`), the call to `load_plugin_textdomain()` within the `init` hook call of the same request still returns `false`, while the localizations of the WP REST Response actually get output in the language corresponding to the locale to which you switch within the `init` hook. So far, any call to `load_plugin_textdomain()` on page load succeeds (returns `true`), while any call to it within a REST request failes (returns `false`). Digging further.